# OrientDb tags synonyms

Tags: discussion, retag-request, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

Is it possible to make synonyms for [orientdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/orientdb) tag:

- [orientdb-2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/orientdb-2.1)
- [orientdb2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/orientdb2.2)

The questions made with these tags are all related to orientdb.

Comment: it will be correct solution

Comment: it would be great!!!

Comment: Note that people (such as yourself) who have more than 2500 rep and a score of 5 or more in the tag can nominate synonyms. Click on the synonyms link at the bottom of the tag excerpt you see when clicking the tag, the textbox at the bottom will allow you to do so. Then you just have to get others to vote :).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: There aren't enough users with a 5+ score in [tag:orientdb2.2] *to* approve any synonyms, and there are only theoretically enough even in [tag:orientdb-2.1]. Just let a mod do it.

Comment: Meh, the numbers are small enough, someone with some time in their hands can and would be faster.

Answer (score 4):

Since there's isn't a volume of questions that justify having 3 separated tags (18 q in the last 7 days and 74 in the last 30, for a 2-3 question/day) this should be done. There isn't a real need for having separated tags for each version and there isn't any important breaking change that justify it either.